# Ionic error - Exec proxy not found for :: Ftp :: connect

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework, ftp

I am currently working on an Ionic application. And the application needs to send an image to FTP.

For this, I am using the Ionic native plugin FTP (cordova-plugin-ftp).

I got two functions:

**1 -** connectFTP():

```
  connectFTP(){
      this.fTP.connect('my_ftp_host', 'my_ftp_user', 'my_ftp_password')
      .then((res: any) => console.log('Login successful', res))
      .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
  }
```

**2 -** uploadFTP():

```
  uploadFTP(){
    this.fTP.upload(this.signatureImage, '/my/path/signature.png');
  }
```

But when I launch it with

> ionic cordova run browser

I got the error :

> Error: exec proxy not found for :: Ftp :: connect

If someone knows why I am getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer alone. So if someone is in the same case as me, you simply can't run ionic FTP on a browser, the supporter platforms are **Android** and **IOS** *(I founded this information in the readme.md inside the package).*